# Определение номера подсвечивающейся строки в таблице

Tags: javascript, html

Есть таблица

```
        <table id="alllistoperators">
```

При движении курсора мыши по таблице подсвечивается строка (на которой остановилась мышь) `<tr>`. Как определить номер этой строки?

Comment: отслеживать ховер-событие наподобие как тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945330/javascript-div-onhover-increment-count только счетчик ховеров убери

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getNumberRow = e => { 
    document.querySelector('.result').innerText = `Номер строки: ${e.target.rowIndex+1}`;
}
document.querySelectorAll('#alllistoperators tr').forEach(item => item.addEventListener('mouseenter',getNumberRow));
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

tr:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
  <table id="alllistoperators"> 
    <tr><td>тест</td><td>тест</td><td>тест</td></tr>
    <tr><td>тест</td><td>тест</td><td>тест</td></tr>
    <tr><td>тест</td><td>тест</td><td>тест</td></tr>
    <tr><td>тест</td><td>тест</td><td>тест</td></tr>
    <tr><td>тест</td><td>тест</td><td>тест</td></tr>
  </table>
  
  <div class="result"></div>
```